# Setting state on array logs empty array multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from a backend server and hold it in an array. After I have done this I want to pass the array to another
component. Although, when I try and populate the array and pass it to my component, I get multiple empty arrays passed rather than an array with data.

I first initialise the state of the array using `useState()`

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

I then have a function that fetches data from the backend and attempts to populate `data`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = () => {
  fetch('/data')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for (const property in data) {
        setDailyCases([...dailyCases].push(`${data[property]}`));
    }
  });
}
fetchData();
},[])
```

When I pass this `data` to another component: `<DataComp data={data}`, I don't get the data I was expecting.

When I `console.log(props.data)` this is the output:

[image: wrong data]

Which is strange beacuse If I `console.log()` while running the data loop all the data is visible:

[image: right data]

How can I make sure the `data` array is updating correctly, and when passed I get one array of all the data?

Here is the `DataComp` component:

```js
const DataComp = (props) => {
  console.log(props.cases)

    return (
      <h1>Testing</h1>
  
    )
}

export default DataComp
```

Using @Fardeen Panjwani answer my component is getting the correct data, although I am now getting more outputs to the console that expected?

[image: console outputs]

Comment: Can you show the entire component's code?

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling `setData` with the fetched data as parameter.

```js
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = () => {
  fetch('/data')
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((_data) => { // using "_data" in order to avoid clash with the state-hook
    setData(_data) // <= this line is responsible for populating the "data" value.
    for (const property in _data) {
        setDailyCases([...dailyCases].push(`${_data[property]}`));
    }
  });
}
fetchData();
},[])
```

In order to update `data`'s value, you need to call the `setData` method.

Comment: This works, although I am still getting more values in the console that expected. Check my edit

Comment: I think that's happening because of re-renders (caused by calling `setDailyCases` inside the for loop). Whenever a component is rendered (or re-rendered) onto the screen, any code that's inside the component body will run, resulting in multiple console.log statements